# WebApi error after enabling the IP address through firewall

Tags: android, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm calling a WebApi from xamarin forms. I'm not using "localhost" but the actual IP address and have enabled this IP address after seeing some post on stackoverflow about the issue but it didn't work. I'm still getting the errors - System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure,System.Net.WebExceptionStatus,System.Net.WebExceptionInternalStatus.RequestFatal

**The stacktrace error:**

> {System.Net.WebException: Failed to connect to /223.0.0.1:44321 ---> Java.Net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /223.0.0.1:44321
> at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0006e] in <89755ea61d9c4ae0a40ce90b872c9e2d>:0
> at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00014] in <89755ea61d9c4ae0a40ce90b872c9e2d>:0
> at Java.Net.HttpURLConnectionInvoker.Connect () [0x0000a] in <2df86f44c8e946618f31cb3aed952f5b>:0
> at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+<>c__DisplayClass44_0.b__0 () [0x0007d] in <2df86f44c8e946618f31cb3aed952f5b>:0
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2476
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

> at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.DoProcessRequest (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, Java.Net.URL javaUrl, Java.Net.HttpURLConnection httpConnection, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+RequestRedirectionState redirectState) [0x0012e] in <2df86f44c8e946618f31cb3aed952f5b>:0
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.DoProcessRequest (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, Java.Net.URL javaUrl, Java.Net.HttpURLConnection httpConnection, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+RequestRedirectionState redirectState) [0x0017e] in <2df86f44c8e946618f31cb3aed952f5b>:0
> at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x002d0] in <2df86f44c8e946618f31cb3aed952f5b>:0
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x0017e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs:506
> at FamilyTreeApp.Pages.UserChildrenTabbedPage.SendURI (System.Uri u, System.Net.Http.HttpContent c) [0x0007f] in C:\Users***\source\repos\FamilyTreeApp\FamilyTreeApp\FamilyTreeApp\Pages\UserChildrenTabbedPage.xaml.cs:211 }

**The codes to call the webAPI(on click of Submit button) in UserChildrenxaml.cs**

```
         static async Task<string> SendURI(Uri u, HttpContent c)
            {
                var response = string.Empty;
                try {
                    using (var client = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
                        {
                            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                            RequestUri = u,
                            Content = c
                        };

                        HttpResponseMessage result = await client.SendAsync(request);
                        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            response = result.StatusCode.ToString();
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    throw ex; 
                }
                return response;
            }

             private async void OnSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                User = new UserInfoTabbedPageViewModel()
                {
                    FirstName = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "FirstName").Value,
                    LastName = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "LastName").Value,
                    Titles = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Titles").Value,
                    Address1 = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Address1").Value,
                    Address2 = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Address2").Value,
                    Age = int.Parse(DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Age").Value.ToString()),
                    City = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "City").Value,
                    Zip = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Zip").Value,
                    Phone = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Phone").Value,
                    State = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "State").Value,
                    Country = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Country").Value,
                    FatherFirstName = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "FatherFirstName").Value,
                    FatherLastName = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "FatherLastName").Value,
                    MotherFirstName = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "MotherFirstName").Value,
                    MotherLastName = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "MotherLastName").Value,
                    Spouse1_FirstName = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Spouse1_FirstName").Value,
                    Spouse1_LastName = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Spouse1_LastName").Value,
                    Spouse2_FirstName = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Spouse2_FirstName").Value,
                    Spouse2_LastName = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Spouse2_LastName").Value,
                    Spouse3_FirstName = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Spouse3_FirstName").Value,
                    Spouse3_LastName = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Spouse3_FirstName").Value,
                    Spouse4_FirstName = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Spouse4_FirstName").Value,
                    Spouse4_LastName = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Spouse4_LastName").Value,
                    Spouse5_FirstName = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Spouse5_FirstName").Value,
                    Spouse5_LastName = DataManager.Instance.Forms1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Spouse5_LastName").Value,
                    Son1_FirstName = User.Son1_FirstName,
                    Son1_LastName = User.Son1_LastName,
                    Son2_FirstName = User.Son2_FirstName,
                    Son2_LastName = User.Son2_LastName,
                    Son3_FirstName = User.Son3_FirstName,
                    Son3_LastName = User.Son3_LastName,
                    Son4_FirstName = User.Son4_FirstName,
                    Son4_LastName = User.Son4_LastName,
                    Son5_FirstName = User.Son5_FirstName,
                    Son5_LastName = User.Son5_LastName,
                    Son6_FirstName = User.Son6_FirstName,
                    Son6_LastName = User.Son6_LastName,
                    Son7_FirstName = User.Son7_FirstName,
                    Son7_LastName = User.Son7_LastName,
                    Son8_FirstName = User.Son8_FirstName,
                    Son8_LastName = User.Son8_LastName,
                    Son9_FirstName = User.Son9_FirstName,
                    Son9_LastName = User.Son9_LastName,
                    Son10_FirstName = User.Son10_FirstName,
                    Son10_LastName = User.Son10_LastName,
                    Daughter1_FirstName = User.Daughter1_FirstName,
                    Daughter1_LastName = User.Daughter1_LastName,
                    Daughter2_FirstName = User.Daughter2_FirstName,
                    Daughter2_LastName = User.Daughter2_LastName,
                    Daughter3_FirstName = User.Daughter3_FirstName,
                    Daughter3_LastName = User.Daughter3_LastName,
                    Daughter4_FirstName = User.Daughter4_FirstName,
                    Daughter4_LastName = User.Daughter4_LastName,
                    Daughter5_FirstName = User.Daughter5_FirstName,
                    Daughter5_LastName = User.Daughter5_LastName,
                    Daughter6_FirstName = User.Daughter6_FirstName,
                    Daughter6_LastName = User.Daughter6_LastName,
                    Daughter7_FirstName = User.Daughter7_FirstName,
                    Daughter7_LastName = User.Daughter7_LastName,
                    Daughter8_FirstName = User.Daughter8_FirstName,
                    Daughter8_LastName = User.Daughter8_LastName,
                    Daughter9_FirstName = User.Daughter9_FirstName,
                    Daughter9_LastName = User.Daughter9_LastName,
                    Daughter10_FirstName = User.Daughter10_FirstName,
                    Daughter10_LastName = User.Daughter10_LastName
                };

                   Uri u = new Uri("http://223.0.0.1:44321/api/FamilyTree/Save");

                string strPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(User);
                HttpContent c = new StringContent(strPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var t =  await Task.Run(() => SendURI(u, c));

            }

        internal class RestHttpClient
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage ResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();

        public async void SendRequestAsync(string adaptiveUri, string xmlRequest)
        {
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                StringContent httpConent = new StringContent(xmlRequest, Encoding.UTF8);

                try
                {
                    ResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(adaptiveUri, httpConent);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ResponseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                    ResponseMessage.ReasonPhrase = string.Format("RestHttpClient.SendRequest failed: {0}", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**WebApi -FamilyTreeController**

```
  using FamilyTreeAPI.DTO;
    using FamilyTreeAPI.Models;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Web.Http;
    using System.Web.SessionState;

    namespace FamilyTreeAPI.Controllers
    {
        [RoutePrefix("api/FamilyTree")]
        public class FamilyTreeController : ApiController, IRequiresSessionState
        {
            [Route("GetAllUsers")]
            [HttpGet]
            [EnableCors]

            public IHttpActionResult GetAllUsers()
            {
                IList<UserDTO> students = null;

                using (var ctx = new FamilyTreeDBEntities())
                {
                    students = ctx.FamilyTreeMasters
                                .Select(s => new UserDTO()).ToList<UserDTO>();
                }

                if (students.Count == 0)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

                return Ok(students);
            }

            [Route("GetUser")]
            [HttpGet]
            [EnableCors]
            public IHttpActionResult GetUser(int UserId)
            {
                IList<UserDTO> users = null;

                using (var ctx = new FamilyTreeDBEntities())
                {
                    users = ctx.FamilyTreeMasters.Where(w => w.UserID == UserId).Select(s => new UserDTO()).ToList<UserDTO>();

                   // students = ctx.FamilyTreeMasters.Where(w=>w.Address2=="hhh").Select(s => new UserDTO()
                   // {
                   //     Id = s.StudentID,
                   //     FirstName = s.FirstName,
                   //     LastName = s.LastName,
                   //}).ToList<UserDTO>();
                }


                if (users.Count == 0)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

                return Ok(users);
            }

            //Get action methods of the previous section
            [Route("Save")]
            [HttpPost]
            [EnableCors]
            public IHttpActionResult Save(UserDTO user)
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                    return BadRequest("Invalid data.");

                using (var ctx = new FamilyTreeDBEntities())
                {
                    ctx.FamilyTreeMasters.Add(new FamilyTreeMaster()
                    {
                        MyPosition = 1,
                        MyParentPosition=1,
                        Title = user.Title,
                        FirstName = user.FirstName,
                        LastName = user.LastName,
                        Phone = user.Phone,
                        Age = user.Age,
                        Profession = user.Profession,
                        Address1 = user.Address1,
                        Address2 = user.Address2,
                        Zip = user.Zip,
                        City = user.City,
                        Country = user.Country,
                        State = user.State,
                        FatherFirstName = user.FatherFirstName,
                        FatherLastName = user.FatherLastName,
                        MotherFirstName = user.MotherFirstName,
                        MotherLastName = user.MotherLastName,
                        Spouse1_FirstName = user.Spouse1_FirstName,
                        Spouse1_LastName = user.Spouse1_LastName,
                        Spouse2_FirstName = user.Spouse2_FirstName,
                        Spouse2_LastName = user.Spouse2_LastName,
                        Spouse3_FirstName = user.Spouse3_FirstName,
                        Spouse3_LastName = user.Spouse3_LastName,
                        Spouse4_FirstName = user.Spouse4_FirstName,
                        Spouse4_LastName = user.Spouse4_LastName,
                        Spouse5_FirstName = user.Spouse5_FirstName,
                        Spouse5_LastName = user.Spouse5_LastName,
                        Son1_FirstName = user.Son1_FirstName,
                        Son1_LastName = user.Son1_LastName,
                        Son2_FirstName = user.Son2_FirstName,
                        Son2_LastName = user.Son2_LastName,
                        Son3_FirstName = user.Son3_FirstName,
                        Son3_LastName = user.Son3_LastName,
                        Son4_FirstName = user.Son4_FirstName,
                        Son4_LastName = user.Son4_LastName,
                        Son5_FirstName = user.Son5_FirstName,
                        Son5_LastName = user.Son5_LastName,
                        Son6_FirstName = user.Son6_FirstName,
                        Son6_LastName = user.Son6_LastName,
                        Son7_FirstName = user.Son7_FirstName,
                        Son7_LastName = user.Son7_LastName,
                        Son8_FirstName = user.Son8_FirstName,
                        Son8_LastName = user.Son8_LastName,
                        Son9_FirstName = user.Son9_FirstName,
                        Son9_LastName = user.Son9_LastName,
                        Son10_FirstName = user.Son10_FirstName,
                        Son10_LastName = user.Son10_LastName,
                        Daughter1_FirstName = user.Daughter1_FirstName,
                        Daughter1_LastName = user.Daughter1_LastName,
                        Daughter2_FirstName = user.Daughter2_FirstName,
                        Daughter2_LastName = user.Daughter2_LastName,
                        Daughter3_FirstName = user.Daughter3_FirstName,
                        Daughter3_LastName = user.Daughter3_LastName,
                        Daughter4_FirstName = user.Daughter4_FirstName,
                        Daughter4_LastName = user.Daughter4_LastName,
                        Daughter5_FirstName = user.Daughter5_FirstName,
                        Daughter5_LastName = user.Daughter5_LastName,
                        Daughter6_FirstName = user.Daughter6_FirstName,
                        Daughter6_LastName = user.Daughter6_LastName,
                        Daughter7_FirstName = user.Daughter7_FirstName,
                        Daughter7_LastName = user.Daughter7_LastName,
                        Daughter8_FirstName = user.Daughter8_FirstName,
                        Daughter8_LastName = user.Daughter8_LastName,
                        Daughter9_FirstName = user.Daughter9_FirstName,
                        Daughter9_LastName = user.Daughter9_LastName,
                        Daughter10_FirstName = user.Daughter10_FirstName,
                        Daughter10_LastName = user.Daughter10_LastName

                    }) ;

                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }

                return Ok();
            }

            [Route("Update")]
            [HttpGet]
            [EnableCors]
            public IHttpActionResult Put(UserDTO user)
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                    return BadRequest("Not a valid model");

                using (var ctx = new FamilyTreeDBEntities())
                {
                    var existingStudent = ctx.FamilyTreeMasters.Where(s => s.UserID == user.UserID)
                                                            .FirstOrDefault<FamilyTreeMaster>();

                    if (existingStudent != null)
                    {
                        existingStudent.FirstName = user.FirstName;
                        existingStudent.LastName = user.LastName;

                        ctx.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                }

                return Ok();
            }

            [Route("Delete")]
            [HttpGet]
            [EnableCors]
            public IHttpActionResult Delete(int userID)
            {
                if (userID <= 0)
                    return BadRequest("Not a valid student id");

                using (var ctx = new FamilyTreeDBEntities())
                {
                    var user = ctx.FamilyTreeMasters
                        .Where(s => s.UserID == userID)
                        .FirstOrDefault();

                    ctx.Entry(user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }

                return Ok();
            }


        }
    }
```

**RouteConfig**

```
        using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Web.Routing;

    namespace FamilyTreeAPI
    {
        public class RouteConfig
        {
            public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
            {
                routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  
                routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "CreateUser",
                  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                  defaults: new { controller = "FamilyTree", action = "Save", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
              );

                routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "GetUser",
                  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                  defaults: new { controller = "FamilyTree", action = "GetUser", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
              );

                routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "UpdateUser",
                 url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                 defaults: new { controller = "FamilyTree", action = "Update", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
             );

                routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DeleteUser",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "FamilyTree", action = "Delete", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
              );

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

Here are the FamilyTreeAPI's property Web where I created a virtual directory and the error in the QuickWatch from thrown exception

[image: Error]

[image: VirtualDirectory]

Comment: have you tested the connection from the device/simulator browser?  This sounds like a connectivity issue to me

Comment: @Jason I've done both running the webAPI(GetAllUsers) from the API project and also call the API action Save(User) from the simulator after entering the values through the simulator. Error is thrown in the HttpResponseMessage result = await client.SendAsync(request); in the SendURI function. I've added and allowed the IP address through the firewall, but I got the above error